# Error Fragmented IP Protocol

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, protocols, wireshark

I am making application in c#.In that application i want to broadcast some data using UDP protocol.I am making socket as

```
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, Convert.ToInt32(ServerPort));
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
 EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)ipep;
 socket.SendTo(m_SendBuffer, ep);
```

Here m_SendBuffer contains data that i want to send.
But whenever i am observing traffic through wireshark it showing protocol IPV4 and showing information as "Fragmented IP Protocol".Please help me why this happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation):

> The Internet Protocol (IP) implements datagram  fragmentation, so that packets may be formed that can pass through a link with a smaller maximum transmission unit (MTU) than the original datagram size.

This means you are sending too large packets.

Comment: If i am using UDP protocol in socket creation then how it shows IPV4 protocol?And my packet size is 90.

Comment: If you don't know the difference between the UDP and IP protocols, you probably shouldn't write networking code and read up on them. UDP is on another "level" than IP and UDP usually runs under IP.

Comment: @svick : I know that "UDP usually runs under IP" but i just want to say that in wirehsark whenever i am capturing data it shows some packets of UDP packet.In my application i am using UDP protocol even after that it showing IPV4. How?

Comment: @svick : For deciding UDP and IPV4 protocol is there any criteria?

Comment: @Dany It is not a choice of deciding between IP and UDP a valid option would be UDP vs. TCP. Look at the TCP/IP Stack. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:UDP_encapsulation.svg

Answer (score 0):

Any given network link will enforce a maximum size on each IP datagram.  The most common is 1500 bytes.  UDP and IP have 28 bytes of headers, so you are left with 1472 bytes for payload.

If you send more than that then each packet will be broken up into fragments.  These are distinguished in the network by the addition of a fragment id in the IP header.  If all fragments arrive at the destination, they will be reassembled into a complete packet before they reach the receiving application.

Fragments are generally bad for several reasons:

- If just one fragment gets dropped, the whole packet is lost.
- The receiver has to spend memory and CPU time buffering and reassembling fragments.
- Lots of things in the network don't like fragments and may drop them for semi-arbitrary reasons.

But avoiding fragmentation is tricky.  Other things in the network, like MPLS, PPPoE, or VPNs may add more headers, reducing the amount of data that you can safely send per packet.  To be safe, keep packets down to less than 1400 bytes.  To be really safe, keep it down below 500 bytes.